# Text doesn't display on mouse over

Tags: html, css

I have an overlay that overlays over an image, and when I mouse over it, it darkens the image. I also have text that is also supposed to display over the image but it doesn't show up on mouse over. Am I missing something here?

http://jsfiddle.net/cryycw3n/

**HTML**

```
<div class="square">
    <div class="info">
        <h2>This is a test</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-image img-responsive square" style="background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/500/500/sports/)"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.square{
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
}
.bg-image{
    background-position: center;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    transition: color .25s ease;
}

.bg-image:before{
    position: absolute;
    content: " ";
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    transition: opacity .25s ease;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

.info{
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin: auto;
    pointer-events: none;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .25s ease;
}

.bg-image:hover:before, .bg-image:hover:before .info{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: I believe you cannot do `::before .info` as you are doing. At least that does not target anything. And the inspector confirms that `opacity` is 0 for the `h2` element containing the text. You need to put the `:hover` selector for the containing element, in your case that would be `.square`.

Comment: Ahh yes, I removed the `:before` and used `.square:hover` instead and now it works!

Comment: So if it works now, remove your question faaaaast, before you get any answers, if not it will be to late to remove it ....

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/cryycw3n/3/)

It's pure css, just add this rule:

```
.square:hover > .info:not(:hover){
    opacity: .4;
}
```

whenever you hover your parent `.square` element, and you are not hovering the text, i.e. you are hovering the image, then show the text with opacity set to your needs.

Hope this is the workaround you are looking for

```css
.square{
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
}
.bg-image{
    background-position: center;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/500/500/sports/);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    transition: color .25s ease;
}

.bg-image:before{
    position: absolute;
    content: " ";
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    transition: opacity .25s ease;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

.info{
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin: auto;
    pointer-events: none;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .25s ease;
}

.bg-image:hover:before, .bg-image:hover:before .info{
    opacity: 1;
}

.square:hover > .info:not(:hover){
    opacity: .4;
}
```

```html
<div class="square">
    <div class="info">
        <h2>This is a test</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="bg-image img-responsive square"></div>
</div>
```